# Zookeeper cluster installation using ansible issue

Tags: ansible, devops, apache-zookeeper

I am using Below github ansible code to implement zookeeper cluster. But I am facing issue for below task.

I am getting the error like below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the github repository

https://github.com/AnsibleShipyard/ansible-zookeeper

The code you put in the question is from `upstart.yml`

`upstart.yml` is included in [`RedHat.yml`](https://github.com/AnsibleShipyard/ansible-zookeeper/blob/9dd39a9555f302c11a10aba35299c1aa9d921741/tasks/RedHat.yml) and [`Debain-tarball.yml`](https://github.com/AnsibleShipyard/ansible-zookeeper/blob/9dd39a9555f302c11a10aba35299c1aa9d921741/tasks/Debian-tarball.yml)

From your error it seems like `Debian-tarball.yml` is getting executed, which i will explain.

`Debian-tarball.yml` has following code

```
- include_tasks: upstart.yml
  when: not zookeeper_debian_systemd_enabled
  tags: deploy
```

While checking the when condition and evaluating `zookeeper_debian_systemd_enabled` ansible is giving error.

`zookeeper_debian_systemd_enabled` var is defined as below in [main.yml](https://github.com/AnsibleShipyard/ansible-zookeeper/blob/9dd39a9555f302c11a10aba35299c1aa9d921741/defaults/main.yml#L9)

```
_ubuntu_1504: "{{ ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version|version_compare(15.04, '>=') }}"
_debian_8: "{{ ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and ansible_distribution_version|version_compare(8.0, '>=') }}"
zookeeper_debian_systemd_enabled: "{{ _ubuntu_1504 or _debian_8 }}"
```

**So the real issue is `version_compare` filter and it is failing there. You might need to upgrade ansible installation to fix this issue.**